# Why does the form action attribute differ with the same code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following razor code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post,...
```

Until today this has produced this HTML (which I want):

```
<form action="/Account/Login" method="post" ...
```

But recently it started to output this HTML:

```
<form action="/form?action=Login&amp;controller=Account" ...
```

What can be the reason for this? I have not changed any of the code in the view or the controller, but it suddely started to output different HTML.

Comment: Did you change the routeconfig? What's the submit type? Looks like it's doing a GET instead of a POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC matches routes in the order that they are registered, and the first match always wins. Most likely you have added another route *before* the route you are are intending this to hit that matches `controller=Account` and `action=Login` (either through convention-based or attribute routing).

```
// Your form will always match this route because it uses the 
// same controller and action values, as a result it can never
// match your Default route.
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "UnintendedMatch",
    url: "form",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: That's excactly what happened.